# Difference between Ctrl C and Ctrl \

Tags: shell

What is the difference between <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl-\</kbd> for terminating a process?

They are both similar though.

Can't find any documentation for <kbd>Ctrl-\</kbd>.

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> sends SIGINT to the foreground process, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>\</kbd> sends SIGQUIT. The default handlers for both of them terminate the process, but the handler for `SIGQUIT` will also create a core dump (unless core dumps are disabled).

See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html) for a list of how all the standard termination signals are processed by default.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> sends `SIGINT` to the foreground process, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>\</kbd> sends `SIGQUIT`. Any difference in how they are handled is due to the signal handlers installed by the process.

Answer (score 1):

To see what keys map to which signals you can type `stty -a` in a terminal. The output will be similar to the following: `intr = ^C; kill = ^U; quit = ^\;`.

The documentation on what the signals mean can be found [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html).